# Is it normal for mke2fs to consume above 100MB or RAM?

Tags: linux, partitioning, memory, filesystems

When I run `mke2fs -t [ext2|ext3|ext4] /dev/sda1` program consumes above 100 MB of memory which can be quite problematic for embedded system. Is that normal behaviour? Is there a way to lower it somehow?

Additional information:

I'm using e2fsprogs 1.41.14.
Tried running it on 1.42.11 with `-D` option which gave me similar results. Which means it's not a I/O cache dirtying issue.

Edit:
Most memory is consumed during creating journal and superblock information.
Memory is freed when program finishes so memory leak can be ruled out.

Another Edit:
I have an idea, not sure how accurate it might be. We've established with  Michael here in the comments (I'm very grateful for your help and time spent on this problem) that I might be unable to fix anything in program itself, but there might be some cache that is writing lots of informations to the memory. Maybe there's some way to figure out which caches program uses and whether they can be disabled or not?

Comment: Doesn't seem *totally* outrageous to me if the file system is large. Just how large a file system are you creating? How are you measuring the memory usage? Please [edit].

Comment: one filesystem on 500GiB drive. I'm afraid of running out of memory. I wonder if I can somehow cut the memory usage. 150-200MiB is a lot if system I'm running got only 512MiB where ~100 is required by Linux that runs everything there.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm running free in ~1s intervals than take top value and subtract it with os memory usage which is somewhat stable. +- 5-10MiB doesn't make much difference in this case.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but if you have some spare storage space, you could create a swap file and use that temporarily during memory-intensive operations. As for memory leaks being ruled out by the memory being freed when the program finishes, I'm not sure you can state that conclusively based on observing external behavior; any memory still held by a process that terminates is (supposed to be) automatically freed by the kernel. Memory allocations are tied to processes, so when the process ends, there is nothing left to claim the memory, hence it becomes available to others.

Comment: I had exact same idea. Although in this case I cannot use swapping due to security reasons. Hardware isn't mine, rules are made by somebody else.
I've ruled out memory leak pretty quickly due to freeing memory after finishing and after reading sources. Was counting on some memory heavy future that I can switch of. Haven't found anything like that so I've asked here. Hoped somebody might have done this before or know some way to free some memory. Anyway. Thanks for your help. I'll prepare report on the problem and hope they'll accept it.

Comment: Cannot use swapping, or cannot risk having sensitive data stored to persistent media in plain text? The latter can easily be solved by running swap through dm-crypt with a random key. If we understand your use case better, it's more likely that someone can propose an answer that actually meets your needs.

Comment: When I've asked got "no swapping at all" answer. "you have to find another solution" so I'm still looking for one.

Comment: You could also try on the official e2fsprogs resources. See https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mailinglists and https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/IRC for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've contacted author of e2fsprogs and asked this question.
After consultation I've upgraded to the newest version (1.43) from github. 
In normal mode not many things have changed. Memory usage is slightly better (90MB instead of 100MB) but -D option (use direct_io omit buffers/caches) while making process twice or three times longer it reduces memory dramatically (~8-10MB). It's worth noticing that I did similar experiment with 1.42.x and haven't reached similar results.

I can accept those results. But they should be considered as partial victory since program while using buffers/caches still eats a lot of memory.

If anyone would like any more information on the topic I'm open for discussion.

I have an idea for workaround of this problem, if I prove this idea to be working I'll post results here